# Which languages are "nnl.", "altn." and "schw."?

Tags: etymology, terminology, dictionary, abbreviation

What do the abbreviations "nnl.", "altn." and "schw." mean in the context of etymology?

Other abbreviations in the same paragraph were "mhd." (mittelhochdeutsch) and "ags." (angelsächsisch). My guess is that "altn." is [Altnordisch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altnordische_Sprache) and "schw." is [Schwäbisch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schw%C3%A4bisch), but I have no idea about "nnl.".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an etymological context the abbreviations you found mean:

**altn.**
[altnordisch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altnordische_Sprache)

**altn.**
[altniederländisch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altniederl%C3%A4ndisch)

**nnl.**
[neuniederländisch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuniederl%C3%A4ndisch)

**schw.**
Dafür gibt es unterschiedliche Verwendungen: Im nordischen Kontext "schwedisch", evtl. auch "schweizerisch" oder "schwäbisch".

*Note:* the abbreviation *schw.* also means *schwach [gebeugt]* in dictionaries.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise that the word after "Schw." was in Swedish -- my mother tongue. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim_N I'm not sure about "Schwedisch". Please check if the word sounds "nordic" :-)